# Error when assigning a Ext.grid.Panel to a Ext.tab.Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

i have a tab-panel which works fine so far,
but as soon as i apply a grid-panel as one of the tabs i'm getting a js-error somewhere in Observerable.js (a class from ext) that say that 'item.on(...)' is not a function after 'item is undefinded'

Here are the appropriate code lines:

This is what i do in my tab panel:

```
initComponent: function() {
        this.items = [{
            xtype: 'profileList',
            title: 'Profiles'
        }];

    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

and here is how the code of my grid panel:

```
Ext.define('BC.view.profile.ProfileList', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.profileList',

    cls: 'profileList',

    border: false,

    initComponent: function(){

        Ext.apply(this, {
            store: 'Profiles',

            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                flex: 1,
            }, {
                text: 'Others',
                dataIndex: 'otherUsers',
                width: 200
            }, {
                text: 'Limit',
                dataIndex: 'limit',
                width: 200
            }]
        });
        console.log('before');
        this.callParent(arguments);
        console.log('after');
    }

});
```

Thanks for any help!

Edit: the first console.log works, the error seems to happen in 'callParent()'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create the items of the tab panel like that:

```
 this.items = [{
        xtype: 'profileList',
        title: 'Profiles'
    }];
```

You should use Ext.apply(... instead:

```
Ext.apply(this,{items:[{
        xtype: 'profileList',
        title: 'Profiles'
    }]);
```